# how do i create random letters in selenium ide?

Tags: random, selenium, ide, names

I'm not an expert in Selenium IDE, I want to declare an array in Selenium IDE HTML and call it in the next line.

```
<tr>
  <td>storeEval</td>
  <td>new Array('en','de','da','cs','fi','fr','it','ja','ko','nl','no','pl','pt','ru','sv','tr')</td>
  <td>myArray</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>type</td>
  <td>FieldName</td>
  <td>${myArray}</td>
</tr>
```

Thanks

Comment: Do you want to retrieve randomly chosen items from this array?

Answer (score 0):

Code below will randomly select item from array and type it to element with `id=FieldName`:

```
<tr>
  <td>storeEval</td>
  <td>var chars = 'en de da cs fi fr it ja ko nl no pl pt ru sv tr'.split(' '); str = chars[Math.floor(Math.random() * chars.length)];</td>
  <td>item</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>type</td>
  <td>FieldName</td>
  <td>${item}</td>
</tr>
```

To access item from your initial array (lets say second item), you can add one more command:

```
<tr>
  <td>storeEval</td> 
  <td>new Array('en','de','da','cs','fi','fr','it','ja','ko','nl','no','pl','pt','ru','sv','tr')</td>
  <td>myArray</td>
</tr>
<tr> 
  <td>getEval</td> 
  <td>storedVars['item'] = storedVars['myArray'][2]</td> 
  <td></td> 
</tr>
<tr> 
  <td>type</td> 
  <td>FieldName</td> 
  <td>${item}</td> 
</tr>
```

You can pass random int in range `[0 .. length_of_array]` to `storedVars['myArray'][randomInt]` to retrieve values randomly.